# twitter api question

Tags: api, twitter

Is there a way to pass a variable to twitter when you authorized and have it pass it back? For instance when I send them to the oauth page I want to send them with an id and when they return to my confirm page I want to be able to get that id. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not set the ID in a cookie (session or otherwise) and then just retrieve it? I mean, that's what cookies are for...

Comment: Thats the right solution but not really applicable to my application because it is written mostly in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to get a response from Twitter when people authorize your (OAuth) application with their account? That's what the OAuth callback is for, you can set it in your application settings on Twitter.